# In laravel, why provide the trailing . character in the prefix

Tags: laravel

In laravel, I had a question about the route name prefix.

> The name method may be used to prefix each route name in the group with a given string. For example, you may want to prefix all of the grouped route's names with admin. The given string is prefixed to the route name exactly as it is specified, so we will be sure to provide the trailing . character in the prefix:

```
Route::name('admin.')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/users', function () {
        // Route assigned name "admin.users"...
    })->name('users');
});
```

I don’t understand the meaning of this sentence:

> The given string is prefixed to the route name exactly as it is specified, so we will be sure to provide the trailing . character in the prefix

In addition to increasing readability, I don’t know the essential difference between adding . and not adding .

Comment: As written, the route name is `admin.users`. If you leave out the `.`, the route name is `adminusers`. The period serves no specific functional purpose that I am aware of. It is a suggestion. You could change it to a hyphen `-` if you prefer. Any delimiter makes it easier to read than mashing the words together.

Comment: @matticustard Yes i think so too.